# Background running app that shows a dialog when orientation changes

Tags: android, multithreading, dialog, orientation-changes, background-service

The title is pretty self explanatory. I want to create an android app that is always running and when the orientation is changed it shows a dialog. I was looking for some information I think I have to use Services but I'm not sure how, which one and why. I'm not even sure that's right.

So, to sum up:
An android app that always (even though it's closed) detects the orientation changes and then show a dialog.

Any help would be nice. I'm really lost right now.

Comment: May I ask what you're using this for? I'm kind of confused because I'm trying to figure out when you would want / need that

Comment: Yes. I'm doing an app that, every time that you change the orientation, asks you if you really want to swap it; as a custom-draggable dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to implement a service and within that service, register a BroadcastListener, listening to a broadcast with the action [ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED). The onReceive() method of the Receiver will be called once anything within the current configuration, like the orientation, changes. Then you can open whatever you need to open from within that service and bring it to the foreground.

I'll leave the details for you, there's too much to be explained. Please read up on [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) and [BroadcastListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). I have not tested this myself either but conceptually I believe this is the way to do it.

Comment: First, very thanks @yorrd now I see it a bit cleaner. I read all the information you passed me and more and I've got a critical question: What kind of service should I use? I mean, a normal `service` (going on the main thread), a new 'thread`, an `intentService`, a `foreground` `service` or a `bound` `service`. I was thinking first on the `foreground` `service` but then I read that I must to create an `ongoing` `notification` and this is so far from my idea. Any help would be so great, and thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome! An intent service handles intents you feed to it - not what you want. A bound service is made to be bound to an activity - not what you want either. Which leaves us with a plain old normal service and a foreground service. The difference here really is only that the foreground service  will try quite hard not to be killed (also Google persistent flag and read up on keeping a service alive if your goal is it to keep it running no matter what).

Comment: If you use a foreground service (which requires the notification) or a normal service is up to you. A normal service DOES run on the main thread, however, that doesn't keep you from creating a new thread inside the service. So to conclude, I would use a normal service. In my opinion you don't even really need to make a new thread because you're not doing any work in there, just listening and then a tiny command to open something.